# How to get items from a list that contain all specific characters from another one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists and i would like to create a third one that only contains items of the first that have all characters from the second one.

I tried some `range()`, `for`, `len()`, etc ideas that i got but got no success at all :/

e.g.

```py
all_types = ['T','L','R','B','TL','TR','TB','LR','LB','BR','TLR','TLB','TRB','LRB','TBLR']
chars = ['R', 'B']
```

To

```py
selected_types = ['BR', 'TBR', 'LRB', 'TBLR']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
selected_types = [t for t in all_types if all(char in t for char in chars)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a set for chars and use its `issubset()` method to filter elements of your list:

```
all_types = ['T','L','R','B','TL','TR','TB','LR','LB','BR','TLR','TLB','TRB','LRB','TBLR']
chars = {'R', 'B'}

selected_types = [ t  for t in all_types if chars.issubset(t) ]
# ['BR', 'TRB', 'LRB', 'TBLR']
```

If you can't change the type of the `chars` variable to a set for some reasons, you could use a filter with a temporary set built on the fly:

```
from functools import partial
selected_types = [*filter(partial(set(chars).issubset),all_types)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all_types = ['T','L','R','B','TL','TR','TB','LR','LB','BR','TLR','TLB','TRB','LRB','TBLR']
chars = ['R', 'B']
selected_types = []


for t in all_types:
    if all([c in t for c in chars]):
        selected_types.append(t)
```

Comment: Nice! One note, `all` is more efficient with a generator than a list, cause it will return early if it finds a false value. `all(c in t for c in chars)` It also takes less memory.